# 2000s starship co-op game with ships like red and blue fighter jets and a human-face ship boss on a desert planet and in space

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, space, video-games

I need help trying to remember an old starship computer game. I wish I could remember how the title screen looked, but it was a co-op game. Player 1 was controlled by mouse, and it was a red fighter jet-looking ship. Player 2 was a blue fighter jet controlled by keyboard.

You would go to different levels, fighting off these mobs of ships. I remember one of the bosses was like a human-face-looking ship. It was on a desert-type planet, but the longer you battled the boss, it would move to space. I think this game was around the 2000s.

Comment: Do you remember if it had 2d or 3d graphics? And was it splitscreen or did both ships  stay in the same screen area?